# How can I majorate the error form the quadrature of Gauss-Radau

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

The quadrature of $f$ is given by $Q_{n}(f)= \sum_\limits{j=0}^{n} A_{j}f(x_{j})$ where $ x_{0} = -1 $ and $ x_{j}$, for $j=1,...,n$, are the zeros of the polymial $\frac{P_{n+1}(x)+P_{n}(x)}{1+x}$ and $P_{n}(x)$ the Legendre Polynomial off degree $n$

Comment: are you trying to estimate the difference between the average and the integral? $$ \big| Q_n(f)-\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\, dx\big| $$

Comment: Yes, a formula that approximates that